# How to pass a return value from beforeAll to a function which triggers spec in jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, specifications

My code as below

```
describe("Smoke-Test-", function() {     
    beforeAll(async function() {
        getSteps = await specGenerator.execute(); //value is returned properly here
        return getSteps //this returns an array object      
    });
  
    beforeAll(async function () {
        const remote = launch.command;
        return page = po.init(remote)
            .maximizeWindow()
            .get(url)
            .sleep(2000);
    });
    
        
    testRunner(getSteps) `//I want to use return value in function and call spec below. Is this possible? Execute function should be run as per the count`
Here getSteps returns Number.
    
    function testRunner(count) {
      it('test', async function () {            
        for(var j=0;j< count;j++)
        {
            execute()                       
        }                           
       });
    }
```

Expected: To get the return value from beforeAll and use it in function to call or trigger spec.

Actual: Returned value is not accessible outside beforeAll.

**Update:**

```
 it('test', async function () {
 console.log(getSteps) //prints value as I moved inside it as suggested
 testRunner(getSteps) //this should trigger testRunner function 
 }
```

But it fails with error,

```
Error: 'it' should only be used in 'describe' function
```

How do we trigger one spec from other spec ?

Answer (score 2):

When you run protractor, it picks up spec files specified in config and builds the queue of `describe`, `it`, `beforeAll` and `afterAll` blocks. IMPORTANT DETAIL HERE IS THAT IT HAPPENS BEFORE THE BROWSER EVEN STARTED.

Look at this example

```
let conditionIsTrue; // undefined
  it('name', () => {
    conditionIsTrue = true;
  })
if (conditionIsTrue) { // still undefined
  it('name', () => {
  })
}
```

By the time Protractor reaches `if()` statement, the value of `conditionIsTrue` is still `undefined`. And it maybe overwritten inside of it block, when browser starts, later on, but not when it builds the queue. So it skips it.

#### In other words, protractor knows which describe blocks it'll run before it even opens the browser, and this queue can NOT be modified during execution

Comment: @sridattas if you post the content of `specGenerator.execute()` I might be able to figure out a workaround

Comment: I learned this very early on when I started working with protractor. I have to explain this to my team on regular basis.

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I updated the function block. specGenerator.execute() returns Number and based on this number testRunner function should get executed. Content of specGenerator.execute() is quiet big.